# Spikes in the signals acquired by Data Acquisition System

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb-design, adc, uart, serial

I am trying to develop a Data Acquisition System (DAQ) to monitor two analog signals. I am using Cy8ckit-059 development board as ADC.

After converting the analog signals to digital, I am transmitting digital data from Cy8ckit-059 to Raspberry pi SBC via UART.

However, as attached, I noted some spikes in the signal when I was monitoring it. The spikes are random in nature and are occuring sometimes (not always). Anyone knows the root cause of the spikes?

Thank you in advance!

BR, Rajat

PS: in the picture 1st signal is channel-1, second signal is channel-2 and last is difference of channel-1 and 2.[image]

Comment: I've had similar problem. ADC was giving 16-bit result, but protocol was designed for 8-bit values only. So program was reading low byte first, then high byte. And sometimes ADC was updating value between these two readings, resulting in similar spikes.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment @Morris. Just 2 questions.. The protocol you mentioned is UART? And were you able to reproduce this noise? it’s very random, and occurs seldom in my case!

Comment: 1. MCU was getting data from ADC via SPI and sending it to PC via UART.
2. I was able to reproduce it from time to time. When i changed the interrupt priority,  noise disappeared.

Comment: Thanks Morris, right now I am trying to reproduce the spikes. I tried various combinations like changing the UART data bits to 9, 7. Changed ADC data to 16 bit as well, however am unable to reproduce them. Please comment (if any).

Comment: Random occurrences are the worst. Can't really help you there - can be anything from faulty cable to repair in office next door. Just think of spikes as one-time anomaly and move on.